# Disabling Two Factor from Trusted IP

Tags: macos, unix

I use two-factor authentication on my Mac for ssh connections, and Google Authenticator app on my iPhone.

This works well, but I have back-up scripts running off cronjobs on my Linux servers, and they periodically rsync the backups to my Mac, which in turn backs them up to TimeMachine.

Obviously, rsync fails, because it is expecting two-factor authentication.

Is there any way on MacOS Sierra, to switch off two-factor authentication when ssh/rsync connections originate on trusted IPs like 192.168.1.0/24 ?

Thanks.